# node js post request.body undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var fs = require('fs');
var router = require('./router/main')(app, fs);

var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Express server has started on port 3000');
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
```

router/main.js

```
module.exports = function(app, fs)
{
  app.post('/addUser/', function(req, res){
        console.log(req.body);
    });
}
```

I use postman tool!! requets param {"password" : "pass","name" : "dltlsdn"}

but... req.body is undefind.... why..??

Comment: can you debug it with devtool (https://mattdesl.svbtle.com/debugging-nodejs-in-chrome-devtools) or put detail, what's in you **res** var ?

Comment: Please check your content-type parameter in postman.
If you want to post an object then make sure that you are using **application/json** content type and if you want to post as  form value then use **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** content type

Answer (score 4):

Reorder the `app.use` statement. Earlier you were processing the request before passing through the body-parser.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var fs = require('fs');

//body parser before routes
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());

var router = require('./router/main')(app, fs);

var server = app.listen(3000, function(){
   console.log('Express server has started on port 3000');
});
```

Hope it helped you.